# Twilio extension failure w/ DB Error: unknown error

Tags: sms, civisms, twilio

Twilio extension worked great for the past year, but fails now. Outgoing messages seem unable to reach the Twilio API, though CRON is working. I've tried different versions of PHP with no effect. I've disabled all plugins except Civi, also with no effect. No changes were made to our extension settings or to our Twilio account configuration.

From the Jobs Log:

> Entity: Job Action: process_sms
>
> Summary
>
> Finished execution of Send Scheduled SMS with result: Failure, Error
>   message: DB Error: unknown error
>
> Details
>
> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
>   a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
>
> Full message:   Finished execution of Send Scheduled SMS with result:
>   Failure, Error message: DB Error: unknown error

That's a bit vague, so I installed a working log viewer extension. Seems we're getting one of these every minute when the CRON job executes and fails to connect with Twilio.

```
 [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array (
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => 
                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,
                                civicrm_phone.phone as phone,
                                civicrm_mailing_event_queue.contact_id,
                                civicrm_mailing_event_queue.hash,
                                NULL as email
                    FROM        civicrm_mailing_event_queue
                    INNER JOIN  civicrm_phone
                            ON  civicrm_mailing_event_queue.phone_id = civicrm_phone.id
                    INNER JOIN  civicrm_contact
                            ON  civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_phone.contact_id
                    LEFT JOIN   civicrm_mailing_event_delivered
                            ON  civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id = civicrm_mailing_event_delivered.event_queue_id
                    LEFT JOIN   civicrm_mailing_event_bounce
                            ON  civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id = civicrm_mailing_event_bounce.event_queue_id
                    WHERE       civicrm_mailing_event_queue.job_id = 807
                        AND     civicrm_mailing_event_delivered.id IS null
                        AND     civicrm_mailing_event_bounce.id IS null
                        AND    ( civicrm_contact.is_opt_out = 0
                        OR       civicrm_contact.do_not_sms = 0 ) [nativecode=1712 ** Index civicrm_mailing_event_queue is corrupted]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => 
                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,
                                civicrm_phone.phone as phone,
                                civicrm_mailing_event_queue.contact_id,
                                civicrm_mailing_event_queue.hash,
                                NULL as email
                    FROM        civicrm_mailing_event_queue
                    INNER JOIN  civicrm_phone
                            ON  civicrm_mailing_event_queue.phone_id = civicrm_phone.id
                    INNER JOIN  civicrm_contact
                            ON  civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_phone.contact_id
                    LEFT JOIN   civicrm_mailing_event_delivered
                            ON  civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id = civicrm_mailing_event_delivered.event_queue_id
                    LEFT JOIN   civicrm_mailing_event_bounce
                            ON  civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id = civicrm_mailing_event_bounce.event_queue_id
                    WHERE       civicrm_mailing_event_queue.job_id = 807
                        AND     civicrm_mailing_event_delivered.id IS null
                        AND     civicrm_mailing_event_bounce.id IS null
                        AND    ( civicrm_contact.is_opt_out = 0
                        OR       civicrm_contact.do_not_sms = 0 ) [nativecode=1712 ** Index civicrm_mailing_event_queue is corrupted]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="
                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,
                                civicrm_phone.phone as phone,
                                civicrm_mailing_event_queue.contact_id,
                                civicrm_mailing_event_queue.hash,
                                NULL as email
                    FROM        civicrm_mailing_event_queue
                    INNER JOIN  civicrm_phone
                            ON  civicrm_mailing_event_queue.phone_id = civicrm_phone.id
                    INNER JOIN  civicrm_contact
                            ON  civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_phone.contact_id
                    LEFT JOIN   civicrm_mailing_event_delivered
                            ON  civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id = civicrm_mailing_event_delivered.event_queue_id
                    LEFT JOIN   civicrm_mailing_event_bounce
                            ON  civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id = civicrm_mailing_event_bounce.event_queue_id
                    WHERE       civicrm_mailing_event_queue.job_id = 807
                        AND     civicrm_mailing_event_delivered.id IS null
                        AND     civicrm_mailing_event_bounce.id IS null
                        AND    ( civicrm_contact.is_opt_out = 0
                        OR       civicrm_contact.do_not_sms = 0 ) [nativecode=1712 ** Index civicrm_mailing_event_queue is corrupted]"] )
```

And here is the corresponding backtrace:

```
 [info] $backTrace = #0 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(948): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "\n                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,\n          ...")
#3 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "\n                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,\n          ...")
#4 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "\n                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,\n          ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "\n                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,\n          ...", "1712 ** Index civicrm_mailing_event_queue is corrupted")
#7 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("\n                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,\n          ...")
#9 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("\n                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,\n          ...")
#10 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("\n                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,\n          ...")
#11 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(438): DB_DataObject->query("\n                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,\n          ...")
#12 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(1125): CRM_Core_DAO->query("\n                    SELECT      civicrm_mailing_event_queue.id,\n          ...")
#13 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(540): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob::findPendingTasks("807", "sms")
#14 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php(199): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob->deliver(Object(org_civicrm_sms_twilio), NULL)
#15 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php(2843): CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob::runJobs(NULL, "sms")
#16 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(380): CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing::processQueue("sms")
#17 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(100): civicrm_api3_job_process_sms((Array:1))
#18 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(169): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#19 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(100): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:9))
#20 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Job", "process_sms", (Array:1), NULL)
#21 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(146): civicrm_api("Job", "process_sms", (Array:1))
#22 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(79): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#23 /REDACTED-PLUGINS-PATH/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php(42): CRM_Core_JobManager->execute()
#24 {main}
```

PHP 7.1.22

CiviCRM 5.12.4

WordPress 5.1.1

Comment: Did you spot the error `Index civicrm_mailing_event_queue is corrupted`. It looks like a MySQL problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop index **civicrm_mailing_event_queue** (table **civicrm_mailing_event_queue**) then re-create it.

After doing this, run the following check:

```
check table civicrm_mailing_event_queue
```

You should get a message that table status is 'OK'.

Comment: Fixed! Wasn't quite as simple as dropping and re-adding though. Attempts to drop gave me "#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column, and it must be defined as a key." But after monkeying with it for several minutes, I got phpMyAdmin to accept an edit of the primary key. At that point, no more corrupt table warnings, and full SMS function via Twilio extension was restored.